# iPhone UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect cancel button does not respond

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sdk

I am observing a different behavior when "presentOpenInMenuFromRect" is executed in iPhone4 and iPad2 (both running in iOS 4.3.5). In iPad2 it is shown a drop down list, with all the applications that can open a specific file, and it works fine; however, in iPhone4 it is also shown a drop down list (and also works fine), but at the end of the drop  down list there is the button "Cancel", which seems to be inactive.

In iPad2 this problem does not happen because the button "Cancel" does not appears, only appears the drop down list, and when I tap onto another area different from the drop down list, this list is closed; which is the desired behavior.

What I mean saying that the button "Cancel", in iPhone/iPhone4, seems to be inactive is: When I touch it, then nothing happens! Well, to be more specific, if I touch it several times in a short period or time, then, later than sooner, the button "Cancel" seems to respond (it changes its color from gray to blue) and then the drop down list is really closed; which is the desired behavior.

I am using the "presentOpenInMenuFromRect" in the following way: I have implemented a "Save" button, which by default is hidden; however, in the method "-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView" I detect the "path extension" of the URL, and if it has the ".pdf" extension, then I show the "Save" button; that is:

```
-  (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if ([[[myWebViewOL.request.URL.absoluteString pathExtension] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
    {
        saveFile0L.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

And the "action" related to the "save" button (saveFile0L) is the following method "saveFile":

```
[saveFile0L addTarget:self action:@selector(saveFile) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

where "saveFile" has the following code:

```
- (void) saveFile
{
    //Do not worry about "FileManager" is only a singleton class
    //which I have defined in order to implement some common methods
    //and one of them is "saveFile:(UIWebView*) withUIView:(UIView*)
    [[FileManager sharedInstance] saveFile:myWebView withUIView:self.view];
}
```

And "saveFile:(UIWebView*)myWebView withUIView:(UIView*)self.view" has the following code:

```
- (void) saveFile:(UIWebView*)webView withUIView:(UIView*)view
{
    NSString* fileName  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
    NSURL* fileurl = [NSURL URLWithString:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileurl];
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* docsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    //UIDocInteractionController API gets the list of devices that support the file type
    docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    [docController retain];
    //Note:[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:view animated:YES]
    //presents a drop down list of the apps that support the file type,
    //clicking on an item in the list will open that app while passing in the file.
    //Note: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fileurl]
    //will return YES if there is an app that can handle the specific file
    BOOL isValid = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fileurl] &&
                    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:view animated:YES]);
    if (!isValid)
    {
        [self showAlertSaveFileError:fileName];
    }
}
```

At present, I do not know how to make work properly the "Cancel" button which only appears in iPhone (not in the iPad) at the end of the drop down list.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I had this problem with the iPhone's list of apps it displays when using the UIDocumentInteractionController. I used a UINavigationContoller embedded inside a UITabBarController for my project, and I noticed that when I displayed the UIDocumentInteractionController list, I couldn't click the cancel button to dismiss the list. I found out, after tapping around the area of the cancel button, that I was incorrectly setting the "...FromRect:CGRect inView:..." parameters. Try tapping areas above and below the cancel button... if that dismisses the list, then change the view or the CGRect as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
BOOL isValid = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fileurl] &&
                    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:view animated:YES]);
```

Try changing `view` `inView:view` to `inView:self.view.window`.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault; finally I could solve the problem.

The mistake was to use "self.view" and passe it as a parameter for the function "presentOpenInMenuFromRect"

[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:view animated:YES]

However, this"view" (self.view) was not be the suitable one to handle the touch events; this mistake could be noticed thanks to the following warning, which was shown in the Xcode console:

```
2011-08-17 18:12:56.389 MyApplication[287:707] Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].
```

This message has given to me the clue and I have modified the code in the following way:

The new and right code is:

```
- (void) saveFile:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString* fileName  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  displayNameAtPath:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
    #if DEBUG
    NSLog(@"<%p %@: %s line:%d> File name:%@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fileName);
    #endif
    NSURL* fileurl = [NSURL URLWithString:webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileurl];
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* docsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    //UIDocInteractionController API gets the list of devices that support the file type
    docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    [docController retain]; //Very important, if "retain" is not called, the application crashes
    //Present a drop down list of the apps that support the file type,
    //clicking on an item in the list will open that app while passing in the file.
    BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:webView animated:YES]; //Using "webView" instead of "self.view"
    if (!isValid)
    {
        [self showAlertSaveFileError:fileName]; //Shows an alert message
    }
}
```

That is, passing to method "presentOpenInMenuFromRect: inView: animated:" the view "webView" (which is a UIWebView), instead of "self.view".

Comment: That'll do it, you can also use `self.view.window` as per my previous answer.